# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I know this title look familiar to some old questions, but I’ve looked at every single one of them, none of them solves. And here is my codes:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\hp user\virtual_flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\hp user\PycharmProjects\flask123\views.py", line 19, in create
create_post = Post(my_form.title.data, my_form.text.data)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

My classes are as follow:

Models.py

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime


class Post(db.Model):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    text = db.Column(db.Text())
    created_time = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    def __init__(self, title, text, created_time=None):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        if created_time is None:
            self.created_time = datetime.utcnow()
        else:
            self.created_time = created_time
```

views.py

```
from app import app, db
from flask import render_template, request, url_for
from forms import CreateForm
from models import Post


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create():
    form = CreateForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('create.html', form=form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            create_post = Post(form.title.data, form.text.data)
            db.session.add(create_post)
            db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
```

I have tried with all possible solution and checked my code for spelling mistakes.But  I found none.

Comment: Possible sources: 1. your `db.Model` base class - whatever it is - do weird things with the `__init__`, 2. in your views.py, `models.Post` is not what you expect it to be (wrong module ? `Post` name shadowed later in the models or view module ?), 3. your `__init__` function is badly indented in you models.py so `Post` uses an inherited `__init__`, 42. someone put a spell on your code. Have you tried inspect what `Post` really is in your view ? Like, you know, with a print statement or the debugger ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The error

> TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

happens at the code

```
create_post = Post(my_form.title.data, my_form.text.data)
```

Instead of passing position arguments to the creation of the `Post` object, pass [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-argument):

```
create_post = Post(title=my_form.title.data, text=my_form.text.data)
```